# Matching a folder tree with a predefined folder tree format

Tags: java

Suppose i have a predefined subfolder tree format like---

```
 /test
    /test/folder1
   /test/ folder2
   /test/ folder3
    /test/folder1/file1.txt
    /test/folder1/file2.txt
    /test/folder2/file3.txt
    /test/folder3/folder4
    /test/folder3/folder4/file4.txt
```

now i want to match the real test folder tree is just as like the predefined tree or not. if any mismatches found it should be detected. how it can be done by java .
means the test folder's hierarchy will be just as like the above mentioned hierarchy. if any mismatches found like --within folder3/folder4 "file4.txt" file is missing it should be detected. when all file and sub-folder will be present under the main test folder it will not show anything otherwise it will show like----
file5.txt is missing in folder3/folder4

Comment: You question is very unclear. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you are unsure of what to include in a question.

Comment: it should iterate through the main folder and should check all folder sub-folder under this whether all file folder are present as the predefined tree format or any file or folder is missing

Comment: simply it should compare between two file tree collection

Answer (score 0):

Well, this little piece of code is supposed to give you the right hint. If I get you right, you have a list/collection of paths which you want to check whether they exist or not. So take the following method, loop through your List/Collection and let "path" be every single Path you want to check. It will always return whether the path exists(works for a path and a path including a file).

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PathExistanceTester {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        // symbolic method name. Here you have to instantiate your list of paths.
        paths = getPathMyTree(); 

        for(String p : paths)
        {
            // p is supposed to look like "/test/folder1/test.txt" or "/test/folder1"
            // depending on your operating system
            Path path = Paths.get(p);

            if(Files.exists(path))
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            else
            {
                // alert
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this is what you were searching for.